# Convert key=value string to JSON

Tags: c#, json, regex

I have a string of keys and values in the following format:

```
KEY1=someValue, KEY2="Hello, World!", SOME.OTHER.KEY=Hello World!, KEY4="Hello, ""World""!"
```

How can I convert it into a JSON string using C#? This can probably be done using a Regex, but I can't come up with the right pattern. Neither was I able to figure out how to do it using libraries like `Newtonsoft.Json`.

The JSON I want to produce is the following:

```
{
    "KEY1":"someValue",
    "KEY2":"Hello, World!",
    "SOME.OTHER.KEY":"Hello World!",
    "KEY4":"Hello, \"World\"!" 
}
```

Comment: What format JSON do you want to produce?

Comment: A complex solution. Start writing logic and people will help.. You need some sort of plugin which would convert invalid to closest valid json string (for c#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with that nested quotes from the updated question things go match trickier. I can't see any viable way of extracting the values with arbitrary level of nested quotes. (This is true for regex approach -- it's still possible to scan the string manually and count the number of subsequent quotes with respect to nesting level.)

Assuming we limit ourselves with only one level of nested quoted strings, the regex would be:

```
(?<key>[^=,\s]+)=(?:"(?<value>(?:[^"]|""[^"]*"")*?)"|(?<value>[^,]*))(?:,|$)
```

Then you can find all matches and reformat the pairs according to JSON rules:

```
var input = @"KEY1=someValue, KEY2=""Hello, World!"", 
    SOME.OTHER.KEY=Hello ""World""!, 
    KEY4=""Hello, """"World""""!"", 
    KEY5=""Hello, """"World""""!"", 
    KEY6=""""""Hello"""", """"World""""!""";
var pairs = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<key>[^=,\s]+)=(?:""(?<value>(?:[^""]|""""[^""]*"""")*?)""|(?<value>[^,]*))(?:,|$)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m =>
        string.Format("  {0}: {1}",
            JsonConvert.ToString(m.Groups["key"].Value),
            JsonConvert.ToString(m.Groups["value"].Value.Replace("\"\"", "\""))));
var json = "{\n" + string.Join(",\n", pairs) + "\n}";
```

Regex explanation:

- `(?<key>` - start a capture group named `key`

  - `[^=,\s]+` - match any non-empty sequence of characters excluding `=`, `,`, and whitespaces
  - `)` - end the `key` group
- `=` - match the equals sign literally
- `(?:` - start an unnamed group used to group alternatives

  - the first alternative - quoted value:
  - `"` - the literal opening quote
  - `(?<value>` - start a capture group named `value`

    - `(?:[^"]|""[^"]*"")*` - match any sequence of non-quotes or quoted string (please not the quotes are doubled)
    - `?` - make the previous match non-greedy
    - `)` - end the `value` group
  - `"` - the literal closing quote
  - `|` - the alternatives delimiter
  - the second alternative - unquoted value:
  - `(?<value>` - start another `value` capture group - .NET regex flavour maintans a stack of named groups so you can access either of alternative capture groups simply by name

    - `[^,]*` - match any sequence not containing commas
    - `)` - end the second `value` group
  - `)` - end the unnamed group
- `(?:,|$)` - match either comma or end of string (both are expected to finish the value)

Comment: This almost works, thank you! But I missed an important detail in the initial revision of my question: there can be quotes inside the value. Please, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed the change. In this case you'll have to escape the `m.Groups["value"].Value`. The easiest way would probably be using `JsonConver.ToString()`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Oh, does deal not quite well the KEY4 value. I'll get back with another update...

Comment: I think `"(?<value>[^"]*)"` => `"(?<value>[^"]*|"")*"` should do the trick.

Comment: @AndreBorges, updated with support of nested quoted strings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `Newtonsoft` as you said.

**Sample Class**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage in some function**

```
public string ConvertJSON()
{
    Person p = new Person();
    p.FirstName = "Khan";
    p.LastName = "Imran";
    string json = "";
    return json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "FirstName": "Khan",
  "LastName" : "Imran"
}
```

Comment: don't directly copy. please be careful before send the answer

Comment: In fact, I haven't tested but this code works I guess.

Comment: The code works, but it doesn't answer the question in any way